# SWFAddress and Thickbox (or JQuery?) Not Playing Nice in IE6/7

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, thickbox, swfaddress

I have a simple little lightbox form, activated by a link in my footer, implemented by the jQuery Thickbox plug-in (v3.1). It works fine in Chrome, Firefox and IE8. But in IE6 and IE7, the lightbox works only intermittently. In most cases, a new window is opened instead. This is not cool.

The thing is, if I remove the reference on that page to SWFAddress.js (v2.3), everything works just fine in all browsers.

I've been pulling out my hair on this one. I tried rolling my own lightbox with jQuery UI, but ran into the same problem.

Has anyone else found a resolution to this issue? A quick web search reveals that others may be running into it, but I've not found a resolution.

Comment: IE always seems to mess things up for developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my own problem: I tried using SWFAddress v2.2, and now everything works just fine. I hope this helps somebody else someday. (And I hope the SWFAddress dev team figures out what the problem is in 2.3 and addresses it. x-))